# Empty data frame is returned after resolve choice is applied to dynamic frame

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am using resolve choice to convert some columns' datatype to double. Below is the code:

```
resolved_data = Get_Data_From_Dynamic_Frame_node1655725248083.resolveChoice(specs = [("items[].dimensions[].item.height.value", "cast:double")]).resolveChoice(specs = [("items[].dimensions[].item.length.value", "cast:double")]).resolveChoice(specs = [("items[].dimensions[].item.width.value", "cast:double")]).resolveChoice(specs = [("items[].dimensions[].item.weight.value", "cast:double")])
```

After this, I convert this dynamic frame to a data frame. The data frame count function return zero and no data is written into s3. Below is the sample data/schema:
[image]

[image]
Am I missing something? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that the dynamic frame contains before this step?

Comment: @RobertKossendey: The screenshots have been added